# What does a superscript after log mean?

Tags: notation, logarithms

In [this paper](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/papers/approximate-majority-disc-2007-proceedings.pdf) they mention an algorithm has big-O time complexity of $O(\log^4n)$, what does the $\log^4$ mean?  I understand $\log_4x$ is the log with base 4 of x.

Comment: $\log$ to the power of $4$ in this case.

Comment: @Thomas so $(log(n))^4$ right?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Comment: This is a horrific notation, jesus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by another user already this must be an **exponent**. The only exception where a superscript would be used for a logarithm to denote the base is as follows:
$^4 log(n)$, which means log base 4.

Comment: Good.  I'm glad there seems to be consensus on this even though it is unusual notation.

Comment: @AJP That notation is quite usual in Europe...

Comment: @imranfat I've seen the $^4log(n)$ before though but never the $log^4(n)$...

Comment: @AJP: I've seen $\log^4(n)$ before but never $^4\log(n)$. (I live in Europe.)

Comment: I don't know if any of the notation discussed is really unusual. $\text{log}^4(n)$ is essentially the same kind of notation as $\text{cos}^4(n)$. I just realized is doesn't use \LaTeX for comments. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: My first guess was that it meant $\log (\log (\log (\log n))))$.  I'm glad it's not.  The instance I saw was $\log^r(n)$.  I didn't want to have to think about an arbitrary number of iterations of $\log$ of $\log$.